# ¿Cuál es el Intent de Android que necesito?

Tags: android, imagen, android-intent

[image: Aplicación para abrir documentos]

Quisiera realizar una aplicación de Android para abrir documentos como la que se muestra en la imagen adjunta pero no se que Intent puedo utilizar para abrir la galería (por ejemplo, abrir la imagen 20180628_140640.jpg que está en el listado de la imagen) y que esta me pueda mostrar en pantalla la imagen en cuestión.

Tal vez no sea un Intent pero cómo o que instrucciones me podrían ayudar a realizar esta tarea. No se mucho de Android, soy nuevo en esto. Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar el Intent normal de android pasandole como parámetro el nombre de la imagen o archivo.

Un ejemplo:

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

            ItemClicked archivo= adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ archivo);
            Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");

            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
             try {
                startActivity(intent);
             } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha habido un error." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } 
          }
    });
```

Comment: Lo que le estás explicando sólo vale para una imagen, no un pdf por ejemplo.

Comment: Te he escrito esto porque con una imagen es sencillo hacerlo, se carga en un Drawable y listo pero un excel por ejemplo no es así, no se puede cargar el excel tan a la ligera. Sería mejor abrir la app propia del teléfono en vez de hacerlo en nuestra app?

Comment: SRT pregunta que intent utilizar para abrir la galería, no para mostrar la imagen en su app:"...pero no se que Intent puedo utilizar para abrir la galería..."

Comment: Tal vez no me di a entender pero si quiero abrir la imagen desde mi app pero no quiero que un imageview la muestre, quiero que la galeria la muestre.

Comment: Hola, me sirvió el código de ejemplo que me proporciono usted y el usuario @David Minaya sin embargo quisiera saber si ¿desde el código puedo seleccionar con que app abrir la imagen y no aparezca el createChooser que me permite elegir la app?

Comment: veo que la gente utiliza esto : Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

Comment: Hola,  muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo resolví de esta manera: intento.setPackage("com.sec.android.gallery3d");

Answer (score 0):

tal como has dicho la forma de hacerlo es utilizando un intent. En [esta](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content) pagina de la documentacion oficial de android explican como hacerlo.

Para hacerlo primero debes de obtener el uri de la imagen. Lo puedes obtener de la siguiente manera:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("Aquí colocas la ruta de la imagen");
```

Después creas el intent:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Titulo"));
```

Y listo.

Referencias:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Android 10 (API nivel 29), Android Sharesheet muestra una vista previa del texto que se comparte. En algunos casos, el texto que se comparte puede ser difícil de comprender. Te recomendamos compartir una URL compleja, como https://www.google.com/search?ei=2rRVXcLkJajM0PEPoLy7oA4. Una vista previa enriquecida ayudará a los usuarios a comprender lo que se comparte.

Mientras se muestra una vista previa del texto, puedes definir un título, una imagen en miniatura o ambas. Agrega una descripción a Intent.EXTRA_TITLE antes de llamar a Intent.createChooser(). Agrega una miniatura relevante mediante ClipData.